# Response from `InvokeRESTAPI` on my Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My `InvokeRESTAPI` displays the following if executed:

[image]

I can see a *Response* field printed that is empty.
Can I somehow use this to get a value back from the API reply and use it to call another template with it?

On the task itself I am using this parameter:

```
successCriteria: eq(root["status"], "successful")
```

So I would assume that if there is some custom success criterion then I would be able to use a value from the response in order to define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, you are using the API to post the json content to Azure Logic App workflow.

So you need to add the **Response Action** in Azure Logic App to add response content to the work flow.

Here are the steps:

In Logic App:

[image]

Then when you run the API in Invoke Rest API task, it will show the customer response.

[image]

For more detailed info, you could refer to this doc: [Construct the response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#construct-the-response)

Comment: Can you also provide an example of using the value of `test` to populate a variable or another task maybe? 

I can see that in your case the `InvokeRESTAPI` task completed with just the `Response` action from the flow. For me, even though I would receive the response the task would still run, so I still had to use an `HTTP` action for the callback. I assume do to `waitForCompletion` being `true`.